# How to place top level frames within another java

Tags: java, image, jframe, containers, imagej

How can I place an imagewindow (http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/gui/ImageWindow.html) which is a top level container, within a Jframe?  Im trying to set up several imagewindows (each with their own images, .tiff files) in an organized manner within a frame.  If i just make 10 of them, they are all loose windows and can be moved around individually.  I want to group all these images together in one collective frame so i can see them side by side

Answer (score 1):

```
How can I place an imagewindow (http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/gui/ImageWindow.html) which is a top level container, within a Jframe?
```

I don't think that is possible to add a top level container (ImageWindow that extends Frame) in another top level container (JFrame).

For what you are trying to do it looks to me like ImageJ might not be the most suitable choice.

I used Dcm4Che to do my image display for an app I wrote.

I had looked into Imagej2 at one a long time ago and at the time I couldn't get it to work at the time so I switched to Dcm4Che. ImaeJ2 will have a better decoupling of the data and the graphics so would be better suited for your needs.